# Rosenthal's Differences of Bounded Semicontinuous Functions I

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

In this [Rosenthal's paper](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/rosenthl/pdf-papers/81.pdf), his texts do not fit the margin, resulting some texts cannot be seen. The paper in his publication webpage is the same.

I emailed him regarding the original manuscript, but he replied that he does not have it anymore.

If anyone has the paper such that texts are fitted in the margin of a pdf, can he or she post a link here? I am interested in the paper, but some sentences cannnot be seen, causing me unable to understand some theorems or propositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of resizing this pdf to fit on the page.  However there isn't a good way of sharing pdf's that I know of.  I don't want to upload to arxiv, since this is not my work.  For similar reasons I don't want to host this on my website, since I don't  own the copyright.

If you send me an email I'll send you the file; if you find a place to host it I'll add the link here.

Note: this offer is not meant to be indefinite; if more than a few days have passed I probably won't have the resized file anymore.